# Bean of type UserDAO that could not be found Spring Boot, Spring Data Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

What could I miss?

> Description: Field userDAO in com.solopov.hillel.uquiz.service.UserService required a bean of type
>   'com.solopov.hillel.uquiz.dao.UserDAO' that could not be found.
>
> Action: Consider defining a bean of type
>   'com.solopov.hillel.uquiz.dao.UserDAO' in your configuration.

Main class:

```
package com.solopov.hillel.uquiz;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class UquizApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(UquizApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

DAO class:

```
package com.solopov.hillel.uquiz.dao;

        import com.solopov.hillel.uquiz.model.User;
        import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
        import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserDAO extends CrudRepository<User,Integer> {
    User findUserByLoginLike(String login);
}
```

Service class which uses DAO:

```
@Service
public class UserService {
    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDAO;


    public boolean addAccount(User user) {
        if (!isRegistered(user)) {
            userDAO.save(user);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Gj

UPD:
After adding the annotation @EnableJpaRepositories
 to the main class, I got an error:

> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report
>   re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 2018-07-19 00:26:08.425
>   ERROR 6810 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication
>   : Application run failed
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'questionController': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'answerDAO'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'answerDAO': Invocation of init method failed;
>   nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed
>   type: interface com.solopov.hillel.uquiz.dao.AnswerDAO    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:587)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:373)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1350)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:580)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]     at
>   com.solopov.hillel.uquiz.UquizApplication.main(UquizApplication.java:12)
>   [classes/:na] Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'answerDAO': Invocation of init method failed;
>   nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed
>   type: interface com.solopov.hillel.uquiz.dao.AnswerDAO    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1708)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:581)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:584)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   ... 19 common frames
>   omitted Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed
>   type: interface com.solopov.hillel.uquiz.dao.AnswerDAO    at
>   org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:473)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]   at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:73)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:66)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:181)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:119)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:102)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:298)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$3(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:287)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:141)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:63)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:290)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:102)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1767)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1704)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   ... 29 common frames
>   omitted

Comment: Are you sure you have annotated your DAO class with Repository and I hope your scanning configuration will look up all these packages. The errors says spring cannot find the bean UserDAO while it is trying to scan the components

Comment: @CrazyMac, If the repository annotation is not enough, how do determine this bean then?

Comment: You will have to somehow tell spring that your UserDAO is a bean, hence you will have to annotate and ensure this package is part of your spring scanning

Comment: Check your scan package <context:component-scan base-package= ???. To see if it can scan your UserDAO package as well

Comment: Code what you show is completely correct, except redundant @Repository. Show the rest of stacktrace.

Comment: @AlexanderPolozov, When I switched to Spring Boot - got less information on the stack. All information about exception showed in the question

Comment: Annotating Spring Data repositories with `@Repository` is unnecessary.

Comment: OP: You didn't show your POM/Gradle file, so are you including `starter-data-jpa`? Do you need `@EnableJpaRepositories`?

Comment: Ok, how you add spring data to project? Do you use spring-boot-starter-data-jpa?

Comment: @CrazyMac how i know- annotation SpringBootApplication has the function of three annotations: Configuration, EnableAutoConfiguraion and ComponentScan

Comment: @chrylis yes, i use this dependency

Comment: there are some kind of magic probably. If all how you say, then should not be any problems. Idk, try to clear project and build again.

Comment: @AlexanderPolozov it's bad dark magic and don't good solution. maybe it will happen again

Comment: @chrylis i added annotation EnableJpaRepositories and get new exceprion, which i added in question

Comment: Missing `'answerDAO'`

Comment: @chrylis thank you, after adding i have exception, which i already fixed! 
You can add answer

Comment: Don't add `@EnableJpaRepositories` as Spring Boot already does that for you. Adding it will disable, parts, of the JPA auto configuration of Spring Boot.